# Set UITableView frame height - incorrect number of rows displayed

Tags: ios, uitableview

Here's some (simplified) test code I'm using to set a table view height:

```
tableView.frame = CGRectMake(tableView.frame.origin.x, 
                             tableView.frame.origin.y, 
                             tableView.frame.size.width, 
                             88);
```

I have the default row height of 44 points. However, the frame only shows 1 row. If I change the height to 132, I get 2 rows displayed.

I'd expect to see 2 rows if I use a height of 88. What am I missing.

Comment: Which row was displayed no the topmost? The first row? Or the second?

Answer (score 0):

Use like-

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 44.0;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 2;
}
```

P.S. -  I have hardcoded this assuming you need only 2 rows of height 44 each. You can customise this if you have sectioned table view or any other custom implementation.

Answer (score 0):

So, after fiddling around with tableView.frame and tableView contentSize, none of which worked, the solution was simply to throw away the tableview in the XIB and do it from code.

e.g.

```
 tView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 20, 200, 200) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
 tView.rowHeight = 40.0;
 tView.delegate = self;
 tView.dataSource = self;
 [self.view addSubview:tView];
```